# How to name vertices with contract.vertices() according to names of mapping vector and add frequency attribute

Tags: r, igraph

Please consider the following graph with vertices of two categories ("digit" and "char"):

```
library(igraph)
id <- c("1","2","A","B")
category <- c("digit","digit","char","char")
from <- c("1","1","2","A","A","B")
to <- c("2","A","A","B","1","2")

nodes <- cbind(id,category)
edges <- cbind(from,to)

g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed=TRUE, vertices=nodes)
```

Now I want to contract the vertices based on the attribute "category":

```
category_attr <- get.vertex.attribute(g, "category")
map = setNames(c(1:2), c("digit","char"))
category_attr <- map[unlist(category_attr)]
igraph_category <- contract.vertices(g, category_attr)
print(get.data.frame(igraph_category, what="vertices"))
#             name
# c("1", "2") 1, 2
# c("A", "B") A, B
```

Yet I would like the "id" and attribute "name" of the new graph to be the "category" of the contracted vertices, and also a column where the number of vertices that were contracted is shown.

In sum, I would like:

```
print(get.data.frame(igraph_category, what="vertices"))
#        name     frequency
# digit    digit    2
# char     char     2
```

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2013-11/msg00175.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is actually easier to use factors to do the contraction.

For your problem, the key is to specify what igraph should do with the vertex attributes when merging vertices. If you don't want the original names to be kept, you can just drop them, and specify that the `category` attribute should be kept. `first` means that igraph just takes the `category` attribute of the first vertex when merging multiple vertices. Since all vertices merged into one have the same `category`, this is good.

Then you can just use the categories as names in the new graph.

```
g2 <- contract.vertices(g, factor(V(g)$category),
                        vertex.attr.comb=list(category="first",
                          name="ignore"))
V(g2)$name <- V(g2)$category
```

`g2` will be a multi-graph (or non-simple graph in another terminology) in this case, it will contain multiple edges between categories, if there was more than one edge between the original vertices belonging to that categories. You can collapse the multiple edges and get the frequency
as an edge attribute.

The easiest is to use the edge attribute `weight`, because this is summed by default when
combining edges:

```
E(g2)$weight <- 1
g3 <- simplify(g2, remove.loops=FALSE)

str(g3, e=T)

# IGRAPH DNW- 2 4 -- 
# + attr: category (v/c), name (v/c), weight (e/n)
# + edges (vertex names) and their attributes:
#             edge weight
# [1] char ->char       1
# [2] char ->digit      2
# [3] digit->char       2
# [4] digit->digit      1
```